# Android SDK http request get process percentage

Tags: android, httprequest

How can I get the process percentage of a HTTP request?
I've got this code for the request:

```
    HttpClient requestclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse requestresponse = requestclient.execute(new HttpGet("example.com"));
    StatusLine requeststatus = requestresponse.getStatusLine();
    if(requeststatus.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
        ByteArrayOutputStream requestoutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        requestresponse.getEntity().writeTo(requestoutput);
        requestoutput.close();
        String requestresult = requestoutput.toString();
        return requestresult;
    } else{.
        requestresponse.getEntity().getContent().close();
        throw new IOException(requeststatus.getReasonPhrase());
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP requests should be run either in an IntentService or AsyncTask. That is, *always* run them in the background.

AsyncTask has methods for displaying the percentage complete: publishProgress() from doInBackground(), and onProgressUpdate() in the main Activity.

An IntentService can show progress by broadcast Intents back to the Activity, or by running a progressBar, or (in JellyBean and later) by using a progress notification.